# Size of words in Siddur; from one blessing to the next in the Amidah

Tags: tefilla, prayer-book, text

I have noticed that some siddurim use different font sizes for different berachot in the Amidah. I initially thought that the larger fonts are used for less frequent parts of the Amidah, to assist the reader in reading the less familiar parts (e.g. "atah echad" in shabbat mincha is often in larger font).

However, I have noticed that even the regular Amidah has some parts in larger and some in smaller fonts, in some siddur editions.

Why is this?

Comment: related (duplicate?): [Font size variation within siddurim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/88697/11501)